# How to access at airflow by kubectl on google-cluoud-composer and airflow 1.10

Tags: airflow, kubectl, worker, google-cloud-composer

I'm using the [GCP Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/), to manage Apache on GCP.

For a new project I'm using the new version of Composer/Airflow (composer: 1.6.1, Airflow:1.10)

To connect at airflow by shell for check a broken DAG the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/testing-dags#faqs_for_testing_workflows) tells:

1. open GCP shell
2. Connect to the GKE cluster
3. *myuser*@cloudshell:~ kubectl get pods
4. *myuser*@cloudshell:~ kubectl exec -it airflow-worker-***1a2b3c***-***xyz12*** -c airflow-worker -- /bin/bash

This work fine with Airflow 1.9 but on Airflow 1.10 **kubectl get pods** don't show worker pod, and I' haven't find documentation about how to access to airflow by kubeclt on AF 1.10

Someone can help me?

```
_myuser_@cloudshell:~ (_Myproject_)$ kubectl get pods 
NAME                                                        READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
airflow-monitoring-564c8c7dc5-hxb62                         1/1       Running     0          17h
airflow-redis-0                                             1/1       Running     0          17h
airflow-sqlproxy-594dbf87b7-nmtbh                           1/1       Running     0          17h
composer-agent-1a871e5e-fa97-4fa3-8843-d0b06718f7f6-rb4rj   0/1       Completed   0          12h
composer-agent-41ee85f8-90f2-45a1-a148-883421775651-jfjz6   0/1       Completed   0          12h
composer-agent-6984c0ef-4a0b-4150-bc6e-8a2996a5c38f-sd45f   0/1       Completed   0          17h
composer-agent-97de1623-5772-496d-a0c0-54adefc00c5a-rq9w6   0/1       Completed   0          12h
composer-agent-b3bc0dc6-6e95-4c9c-91d0-735755c2210f-tcxgg   0/1       Completed   0          73m
composer-fluentd-daemon-bkn28                               1/1       Running     133        17h
composer-fluentd-daemon-jvdlc                               1/1       Running     133        17h
composer-fluentd-daemon-lchq9                               1/1       Running     133        17h
composer-fluentd-daemon-wfzzr                               1/1       Running     133        17h
```

Answer (score 5):

To accommodate in-place version upgrades, Cloud Composer now runs version-specific pods (the worker and the scheduler) in a non-default namespace that is named after the running versions. For example, this is what it might look like:

```sh
$ kubectl get ns | grep composer  # ns = namespaces
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   Active   2d
```

You can then look for cluster resources specifically in that namespace:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec
NAME                                 READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
airflow-database-init-job-mhn87      0/1     Completed   0          2d
airflow-scheduler-748ff8dc88-g2k5q   2/2     Running     0          2d
airflow-worker-5767579d-csvcg        2/2     Running     0          2d
airflow-worker-5767579d-d8fgd        2/2     Running     0          2d
airflow-worker-5767579d-tlwpc        2/2     Running     0          2d
```

If more convenient, you can also list resources in *all* namespaces:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  # or -A
```

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep airflow
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   airflow-database-init-job-mhn87                                  0/1     Completed   0          2d
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   airflow-scheduler-748ff8dc88-g2k5q                               2/2     Running     0          2d
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   airflow-worker-5767579d-csvcg                                    2/2     Running     0          2d
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   airflow-worker-5767579d-d8fgd                                    2/2     Running     0          2d
composer-1-6-1-airflow-1-10-1-04c210ec   airflow-worker-5767579d-tlwpc                                    2/2     Running     0          2d
default                                  airflow-monitoring-f78cd5c75-2n727                               1/1     Running     0          2d
default                                  airflow-redis-0                                                  1/1     Running     0          2d
default                                  airflow-sqlproxy-57b7976d59-qnkm7                                1/1     Running     0          2d
```

---

Example for how to SSH to one of the worker or scheduler pods:

```sh
# Long form
$ kubectl exec \
   --stdin --tty \
   --namespace=composer-1-8-1-airflow-1-10-3-6e595c80 
   airflow-scheduler-58948b8956-4sxwt /bin/bash

# Short form
$ kubectl exec -it \
   -n composer-1-8-1-airflow-1-10-3-6e595c80
   airflow-scheduler-58948b8956-4sxwt bash
```

Comment: K8 is at version 1.19 as of 04Dec2020 and there's been a slight syntax change to get access to a K8 container: `kubectl exec --stdin --tty --namespace <target namespace> <pod's name> -- /bin/bash`. The double dash `--` prior to `/bin/bash` is now necessary.